# How to fill the screen with TableView cells? Swift

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a `TableView` and dynamic cells but they dont go all the way down to fill the screen, it can only scroll inside that little section. How can I change this in storyboard? Thanks!

P.S. apologies if this is a super basic question, I just dont know how to do it.

[image]

Comment: Are you using auto layout? Or, try to locate it programmatically ?

Comment: Use auto layout and pin it to the top, bottom, leading space, and trailing space... then it will always fill the screen real estate that you have

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog also remove the "relative to margin" flags when setting it up

Comment: @Gasim its "constrain to margins", but true definitely need to make sure that box is unchecked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're table view is not filling the whole screen. Not that cells are not filling the table view.

To fix this you need to use auto layout and pin each side to bottom, top, trailing, leading respectively.

*(You do that by clicking on the little TIE-fighter in the bottom right corner of the storyboard... :) )*